# .html files showing up as "listing directory" when opening live server

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am opening up a new file in a new folder in vscode. When I open up the new .html file in live server, it opens it up as a "listing directory." When I create a new file in an old folder it works perfectly fine. I tried creating different folders and they all open up as "listing directory." I even opened up the instructors file of the lesson in vscode and it gives me the same "listing directory" tab. Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) First option is obviously setting the main html file named as `index.html` but as you mentioned it didn't work right!

well the file you are trying to open has also need to be opened in `vs code` too!

[image]

As you can see in the above screenshot it is not rendering the `work.html`

---

You must have to open the file in `vscode editor also`

[image]

Then you can simply press `F1` and write `open with live server`

[image]

Comment: The index.html file doesn't work for me. I tried it and still shows up as a listing directory. I also don't have an index.html in a couple of my previous folders and they work fine. It is just this new one that I am trying to add and it doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @BusterThomas I have edited the answer, do let me know if it help?

Comment: I tried that as well and I didn't have any luck with that either. This just isn't making any sense. Do you think I should just delete the program off the computer and then download it again? I still haven't found an explanation as to why none of these steps are working.

Comment: can you tell me how do you add folder to your `Vscode`, are you adding `workspace`or adding a `folder` in `VS`

Comment: But as you mentioned it is working with your previous folder so probably nothing wrong with software

Comment: Thanks!! I created my folder on my desktop this time and then dragged it over and added to my worskspace and now it is working. My next question is, why wouldn't it work if I created as a subfolder on my desktop and then added it? Meaning: desktop > Udemy > htmlcss > css2.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the .html files to work. I had to add the main folder to the workspace. For example, my folders look like this: documents > udemy > htmlcss > (multiple folders). When I tried to just add a new folder inside of htmlcss and drag it over to the workspace it would give me "listing directory." When I added the htmlcss folder to the workspace, the .html files worked like normal!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, however, I noticed if the folder in the `workspace` ended with a number it wouldn't work and would display the `listing directory/` page. Taking the number out of the folder seemed to work, even a number at the start would still work. It only seemed to be a number at the end that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I moved index.html file out of all folders and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The extension basically opens in a live server the documents in New Tab:
[Image of the tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cif7C.png)

The project should be there in order for LiveServer to work!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is happening just because you were opening live server from your js file instead HTML file.
Open live server from your HTML file.
It will solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Open it from the folder, I had the same problem and it worked for me. I think that the live server extension has a problem.